# Installing multiple different instances of wordpress on the same website

Tags: wordpress, installation, themes, cpanel, subdirectory

I currently have a website up and running that is my freelancing website.  What I wanted to do was create a testing subdirectory on the website.

So for example my site would be:
website.com

I want the testing site to be: website.com/test
I need this test to be private and require a password to view, as well as be a different installation of wordpress so I can manipulate it without editing my main website.  Is this possible?  Currently I have created a test directory from the cPanel that requires a password but it just brings me to a 404 not found page.

I would also like to create more, public, instances that I can use as a portfolio until I get more real clients.  So for example I would like to have my site be: website.com/themeOne

Is any of this possible, or am I out of luck?  Please let me know I would greatly appreciate any help.  Anything I found found online thus far has either not been relevant or has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting up a wordpress multisite installation. I currently use this to host all my clients.

Will work like this.. Main site is website.com

Depending on how long you have had that site set up will determine whether your multisite install will be a subdirectory or a subdomain. If you have had your main site for a while it will be subdomains. ie. xyz.website.com

You will have to set up a wild card subdomain on your server though...so keep that in mind.

Here is the documentation on setting up a wordpress multisite

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/

Answer (score 0):

You can install as many WordPress instances as you like in subfolders `example.com/test/` or subdomains `test.example.com` in one hosting account; see http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs. (You are, of course, limited if your host does not support subdomains. And you may find lots of sites with lots of traffic will slow your whole hosting account.)

For these separate WordPress installs, you can use the same database; simply give each WordPress install a different database table prefix in wp-config.php. https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Or, give them all the installs a totally different databases, only limited by your hosting account.

To control access to a WordPress site, there is no need for access control in .htaccess or via Cpanel; use any one of a number of plugins that allow you to restrict access to anyone not logged into WordPress. See https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=password

And you can still control the user's role when they are logged into the site with one of those plugins, i.e. editor, administrator, etc., from within WordPress. That's because you want to give a client a Subscriber user level so they can simply login and view the site, rather than Administrator, who can see posts, plugins, etc. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

There is no need for WordPress Multisite, unless you want to go that way: see https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network But be aware that MS requires more server and DNS configurations if you want to use Domain Mapping: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/